# Bootstrap 3.0 long list text and badge

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Consider a list with badge in bootstrap 3.

If a list text is very long, the badge will remain in first line. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/eXxQj/

```
    <div>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"> 
               <span class="badge">27363 363 364 464 4654 6134232 32 262</span>
                  A very long text and a very long text and a 
                  very long text and a very long text and a very long text and a very  
                  long text and </li>
            <li class="list-group-item"> <span class="badge">2</span>
                 small text</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"> <span class="badge">1</span>
                 small text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Is it possible to align the badge at the middle of the text?! I tried below but it did not helped! :

```
<li class="list-group-item"> <span class="badge">123</span>
    <span style="vertical-align:middle;">
       Long text
    </span>
</li>
```

Here is what I want

```
a very long text 
very               (badge)
long text...
```

Comment: `vertical-align` generally only works with the `<img>` tag.

Comment: R you want set the text middle or badge middle??

Comment: please see the update, badge in the middle of the text

Answer (score 0):

You could fix this with adding `margin-top:15px`to the element in question, but this may not be suitable if you are creating the list dynamically.